# How to connect two displays to laptop and keep laptop display on as well?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop and two monitors. I need to use all of them and have three displays. Current settings in Windows only allows me to extend one display and keep one as a main display. Does anyone know a way to connect both displays to my Windows 7 PC?

Comment: How many ports do you have on your laptop? It may not be possible. I have a y510p, and I am able to use the hdmi and vga ports with my laptop screen to get three monitors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computers and would be a better fit at SuperUser

Comment: A lot of this depends on what hardware you have and what software you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try purchasing a USB to HDMI adapter. Check out Amazon or Newegg.

Comment: For those wanting to take advantage of their existing graphics processor something like the [Matrox TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital/) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using USB/HDMI adapter would let you connect it, but since you say the system itself won't let you connect more than 1 extra, it may not show up.

Anyways you should check if your processor is capable of handling more than 2 monitors.